# phpmyadmin produces errors browsing empty table

Tags: phpmyadmin

Just upgraded to phpmyadmin 4.9.5 (from 4.9.4) running ubuntu 18 server, php 7.4.5 and get errors when trying to browse an empty table. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the errors, exactly? Do you get the same errors on a table that has data in it?

Answer (score 0):

Making the following changes to phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php did the trick for PHPMyAdmin 4.9.5deb2:

line 4442

`$column_for_first_row = $row[$sorted_column_index];` -> `$column_for_first_row = $row[$sorted_column_index] ?? 0;`

and line 4468

`$column_for_last_row = $row[$sorted_column_index];` -> `$column_for_last_row = $row[$sorted_column_index] ?? 0;`

Please be advised when making these changes as you *might* break something.